# How can I print multiple lines of text with random session number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The title may be a bit misleading, but what I'm trying to do is create a Python script that allows me to generate multiple strings at once.

Essentially, I want to print out multiple lines of `ProxyString` with a random session number. How would I print out multiple lines at once?

```
#Proxy String Generator
import random

ProxyString = "uname--user--country--us--session--"
for x in range(10):
    session = random.randint(1295049392,9982487654)
print (ProxyString, session)
```

Comment: I put the code in a block... did I get it right? In python, code suites like the for loop are delimited by indentation - the print is outside of the `for` so it only prints a single time after 9 of your session values have been silently discarded. Indent the print to be directly below the `session = ...` line and it will print more often.

Comment: ... and promise that you will use 4 spaces per indentation as suggested in the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the poor formatting, im brand new to writing code and this stackoverflow. I appreciate the feedback :)

Comment: So when running the script, its printing out the lines like this
(host:port:uname--user--country--us--session--', session, ':password')

How would I be able to print the lines without it having the , seperations

Comment: @tripleee after the last edits the print statement is correctly indented and the question is moot? I think this might have been by the edit of VirtualScooter and you edited later?

Comment: Yeah, looks like @VirtualScooter's edit fixed too much. I'll revert that. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you.

If you want to print all the random numbers then you should see weather the indentation of the print statement is with the session variable as in Python indentation is very necessary to take care of.

The problem with your code was that it was not indented properly

```
#Proxy String Generator
import random

ProxyString = "uname--user--country--us--session--"

for x in range(10):
    session = random.randint(1295049392,9982487654)
    print (ProxyString, session)
```

If this is what you have wanted, write down in  the comment below I will explain my answer in detail.

**EXPLANATION:**

Python code is executed line by line in the interpreter

When we use a for loop and put something inside it, the loop run as many time till the given logic is not set to false thereby when you use

```
for x in range(10):
```

What this statement does is every time this code runs

1. List item
2. It will take the value of variable x, and increment the value in x by 1 every time it loops

So if you want to print() the number for each variable value then it should be indented in the for loop.

Your problem was that you had printed the variable session after the loop ended that's why you only get one value that is of the last time the loop is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The code now prints out like this

('uname--user--country--us--session--', 5666017329)

Is there anyway I would be able to print the lines without the commas and parenthesis?

Im brand new to python and programming in general.... Please excuse the noob questions while I learn some more about what im actually doing :)

Comment: @jstarvs I have added the explanation you can go through that. And please if my anser helped then pls mark my Answer by click on the tick mark besides the answer.